# How can I get meson to determine the Dynamic Linker on Windows OS?

Tags: meson-build

I'm trying to do a meson build, but getting this error: meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unable to determine dynamic linker
I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: I was able to find an answer here... https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GLib/SupportedPlatforms So I put the VS 2017 compiler in the path environment, but now I get a new error: Compiler cl can not compile programs. Edit - The log file says this: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib' This, although the file exists.

Comment: I just discovered I don't need meson, as msys2 gets all the libraries I need - no problem.